# Broken turbocharger - what is the best option, repair, buy new or find a used one?

Tags: turbocharger

My car is a VW Golf 5 1.9 TDI (77 kw), year 2005.

After establishing that my turbocharger was destroyed I had three options to choose from.

There is more insight to what happened in the next question
[Oil draining out shortly after turbo hose detached/broke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/67899/oil-draining-out-shortly-after-turbo-hose-detached-broke).

1. Search for a matching turbocharger from a car that was taken apart. - The issue in this case is that there is no guarantee will it work and how long will it work.
2. Repair the same turbocharger for something around 250 euros - The company that is doing the repair gives a 6 month guarantee (which I guess is not much at all)
3. Buy a new turbocharger - The issue here is that first of all it was the most expensive option starting at around 500 euros and going further and that would mostly be a third party that would develop the part, the part being OEM would maybe cost me above 1000 euros. Note that I'm from Macedonia and prices may vary from other locations.

I decided to repair the existing turbocharger and I want to know was that the right thing to do under the circumstances? Obviously I still have the chance to change my decision.

Comment: It will be hard for us to answer this as it's really dependent on your own risk/reward decision (how much do you want to spend to ensure you won't have a chance at failure in the future?) - and, there's the fact that your maintenance habits will impact this (frequent oil changes with high quality oil will help avoid cooking the turbo).

Comment: I'm closing this under it being opinion based. Realistically, you did what was right for your pocketbook in the end. We can't make that decision for you. However, if you'd like to *discuss it*, we can always take it up in [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), this Stack's chatroom.

Comment: Worth noting that « oem » turbos are made by companies like Garrett etc ie they are third parties...